# forest column alignment/formatting

Tags: alignment, forest

I'm trying to create two trees describing two experiments that are visually aligned, but where the 2nd diagram (M2) has 1 fewer categories. If I just remove the 4th category, it moves the entire 4th column, and recenters the 2nd tree, which is not what I want. I would like the following:

1. Remove the 4th box "fruit type" in the second tree, but keep the column alignment with the first tree.
2. Make sure that the all the boxes under the "outcome" column (both the first and second tree) are (a) of the same width, and (b) aligned. Currently, the boxes in the second tree have varying width size with the inclusion of the N of observations, and I suspect if I put longer text inside, it might even mess up the alignment with the first tree.

Desired outcome:

[image]

What I do NOT want:

[image]

Below is the current code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\tikzset{mybrace/.style={decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm}, ultra thick, transform canvas={xshift=1mm}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Experimental Conditions and the Number of Observations}
\medskip

\newcommand*{\equal}{=}

% tier/.pgfmath=level()
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east, if level=0{l sep=-5mm}{if n children=0{minimum width=28mm}{minimum width=28mm}}}
[
    [Versions, for tree={no edge, draw}[fruit type[outcome[fruit type]]]
    ]
    [M1, no edge, for descendants={forked edge, draw}
        [Apple[cheap[Apple (N{\equal}60), name=A1][Banana (N{\equal}67)]][expensive[Apple (N{\equal}74)][Banana (N{\equal}84)]]]
        [Banana[cheap[Apple (N{\equal}80)][Banana (N{\equal}84)]][expensive[Apple (N{\equal}84)][Banana (N{\equal}73), name=B1]]]
    ]]
\end{forest}

\medskip
\medskip
\medskip
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east, if level=0{l sep=-5mm}{if n children=0{minimum width=28mm}{minimum width=28mm}}}
[
    [Versions, for tree={no edge, draw}[fruit type[outcome[fruit type]]]
    ]
    [M2, no edge, for descendants={forked edge, draw}
        [Apple[cheap(N{\equal}144)][expensive(N{\equal}171)]]
        [Banana[cheap(N{\equal}161)][expensive(N{\equal}133)]]
    ]]
\end{forest}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cleaned up your tree a bit. Here is the result.

- You can combine the two trees into one, with an empty root node. Then the alignment is automatic.
- You select the `minimum width` for each level, or just use a large enough one so all nodes are equal.
- Instead of defining `\equal` you can enclose the node content in `{...}`
- `fit=rectangle` will prevent the subtrees from overlapping vertically.
- `delay={content=#1\strut}, inner ysep=2pt` will add a `\strut` to each node so that they all have the same height. You can then adjust the `inner ysep` to get the height you want.
- For the lower tree, add `before drawing tree={y-=10mm}` to add additional vertical space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Experimental Conditions and the Number of Observations}
\medskip

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    grow'=east,
    forked edge, 
    delay={content=#1\strut}, inner ysep=2pt,
    if level=1{no edge, minimum width=18mm}{draw, if level=2{minimum width=18mm}{if level=3{minimum width=31mm}{minimum width=40mm}}}
}
[, coordinate
    [Versions, for tree={no edge, draw}[fruit type[outcome[fruit type]]]
    ]
    [M1, fit=rectangle
        [Apple[cheap[{Apple (N=60)}, name=A1][{Banana (N=67)}]][expensive[{Apple (N=74)}][{Banana (N=84)}]]]
        [Banana[cheap[{Apple (N=80)}][{Banana (N=84)}]][expensive[{Apple (N=84)}][{Banana (N=73)}, name=B1]]]
    ]
    [M2, fit=rectangle, for tree={before drawing tree={y-=10mm}}
        [Apple[{cheap(N=144)}][{expensive(N=171)}]]
        [Banana[{cheap(N=161)}][{expensive(N=133)}]]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Two follow up question: a) I got rid of the repeated headings but I can't figure out how to add space between the two trees so the boxes aren't too closer to with one another. I added \medskip but it doesn't seem to work b) Now the title "Experimental Conditions and the Number of Observations" is not centered anymore, even though I have /centering in the code. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Also, could you clarify how I set each box width separately? If I try something like `for tree={grow'=east, forked edge, if level=1{minimum width=31mm}{no edge, l sep=0, l-=5mm}{if level=0{coordinate}{minimum width=24mm}}}` it prints out a bunch of errors.  I would like just the outcome column to be a big wider, and the rest smaller.

Comment: @ravman: I edited my response to address these requests.